# Nginx - PHP-FPM Image Uploading reset every few seconds

Tags: nginx, php

I am using Nginx with PHP-FPM
I have added the following line in the php file.

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

It is not uploading the image. I guess it tries to upload for 30 seconds. If the image is not uploaded by that time, It stops uploading. But small images are successfully uploaded.

I tried to change the keepalive_timeout to 300.
Still I am facing the same problem.

I was previously using apache + nginx. I just moving it to nginx + PHP-FPM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the following in your nginx.conf

```
client_max_body_size 2M;
```

It will allow to upload upto 2MB of image size.